# TAILS & CHROME/ FFOX

Tags: tails

When using TAILS, I sometimes need to open things in a non-tor browser to get them to open/ work. I downloaded chrome and have the .exe file, but don't know what to do with it after it downloads to my tails downloads. I am not a linux aficianado. But I imagine it is not too difficult.

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the unsafe browser under the Internet tab of applications? It will work just like a normal firefox/iceweasel brower.

Answer (score 0):

There's no use for dot-exe file in Linux - unless you're trying to perform a difficult emulation setup. If you're not a Linux pro - install Virtualbox from your distro's repository and run the browser *inside the VM* routed through Tor to properly isolate it. If you need help in setting it up - just say it, and we will do it